# Array to hash with multiple keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

How do I turn this:

```
[[3, 18], [5, 20], [7, 22]]
```

into this:

```
[
  {:quantity=>3, :price=>18},
  {:quantity=>5, :price=>20},
  {:quantity=>7, :price=>22}
]
```

Hoping to get a one-liner answer, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
a = [[3, 18], [5, 20], [7, 22]]
a.map { |item| {quantity: item[0], price: item[1]} }
# => [{:quantity=>3, :price=>18},
#     {:quantity=>5, :price=>20},
#     {:quantity=>7, :price=>22}]

a.map { |q, p| {quantity: q, price: p} }
# => [{:quantity=>3, :price=>18},
#     {:quantity=>5, :price=>20},
#     {:quantity=>7, :price=>22}]

a.map { |item| Hash[[:quantity, :price].zip(item)] }
# => [{:quantity=>3, :price=>18},
#     {:quantity=>5, :price=>20},
#     {:quantity=>7, :price=>22}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do as below using [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

```
a = [[3, 18], [5, 20], [7, 22]]
a.map { |v1,v2| {:quantity => v1, :price => v2} }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of beating a dead horse, my version, with imo better naming

```
a.map {|(quantity, price)| {quantity: quantity, price: price} }
```